# Modals with ngx-bootstrap give me error: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined

Tags: visual-studio, angular, typescript, bootstrap-modal, ngx-bootstrap

I'm bulding an app in Angular2 with visual studio 2015: There are two buttons in the main page that both give a same popup window. Everything worked good until I decided to make a separate component for this modal. So buttons stay still in main page and modal is now in another component. But now I got the error :Cannot read property 'show' of undefined! on my show function.
Here is modal.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-info-modal',
  templateUrl: './info-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./info-modal.component.scss']
})
export class InfoModalComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('lgModal') public lgModal:ModalDirective;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  showInfoModal = () => {
    this.lgModal.show();
  };
}
```

Here is modal.component.html:

```
<div bsModal #lgModal="bs-modal" [config]="{backdrop: 'static'}" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h2 class="modal-title pull-left">what is it about?</h2>
        <button type="button" class="close pull-right" (click)="lgModal.hide()" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>content of the window.....</p>
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

The button in main page component html:

```
<button class="btn-default btn pull-right next" (click)="showModal()"> privacy <i class="fa fa-fw fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
```

Homepage component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(){

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    }

  showModal() {
    this.infoModal.showInfoModal();
  }
```

Do anyone has any idea? I don't know where I made mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the below for your `ViewChild` reference

```
@ViewChild(ModalDirective) public lgModal:ModalDirective;
```

**Update 1 : Based on revised question**

You are missing the `infoModal` refernce as below,

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
@ViewChild(InfoModalComponent)  infoModal : InfoModalComponent; ////// missing declaration

  ngOnInit() {
    }

  showModal() {
    this.infoModal.showInfoModal();
  }
```

Note : As you are using `this.infoModal` you need to declare it as above, else you can use them in the HTML itself as

```
<button class="btn-default btn pull-right next" (click)="infoModal.showInfoModal()">
Show Information
</button>

<app-info-modal #infoModal> </app-info-modal>
```

Comment: I rewrote it with services and it works. Thanks anyway for your comment. [with this I mean](http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#service-template)